# Is it possible to achieve my goal by using Beacons

Tags: ibeacon, ibeacon-android, beacon

I have a mobile IOS application which is basically group chat oriented. I was wondering if I can make it beacon-enabled app. With other words, application which can detect beacons, determine id, receive short ads etc. I am quite new to beacons, still reading a lot about it. I found  [this article](http://developer.estimote.com/nearables/build-a-nearables-app/) which makes me believe that maybe it is possible to achieve my goal.

I want my app, except for its original functionality, to be able to:

- Detect a beacon (even if app is in background, without the need to have been paired or whatever)
- Receive simple ads by the beacon (while using the app in a certain mode, to be able to project the ads on phone's screen)
- Read some real-time info(if required by the user) like: speed(if moving beacon), temperature etc.

In order to achieve all that I would like not to disturb the end user by making him download additional stuff related to the beacon. I want him to have my app and that's all.

Comment: Yes, this is all possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor for beacons while your app is in the background. You can do this by using the CoreLocation Framework or by using a framework of your beacon supplier. (e.g. Estimote)

To the ads: The beacon will only deliver its pre configured ids. (UUID + Major + Minor). If you want to receive ads, you must have a Webservice that will get your beacon ids and return you the ad to display.
(If the ads never change, you can put them directly into your app without a webservice)

How you will show the ads in your app is completely open to you.

I don't really understand what you mean with real-time-info. There are beacons that also send you TLM. So you can get the temperature and the battery level of the beacon. I've never seen moving beacons or beacons that can transmit their speed.

Some useful links:

https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/

https://xamoom.com/en/2016/07/ibeacon-for-developers/

Comment: "I've never seen moving beacons or beacons" - What if I attach the beacon to a moving object. E.g. bus, car. You are in the bus and you'd like to know what's the speed we are going with.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. 
In that case your beacon hardware needs to have a velocity sensor.
The maybe better way will be to get the speed from the device (eg gps).